# To fetch data from one page to another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question  has been answered before, but i have difficulty among those. There is a textfield on one page and i want to retrieve that it's content into label which is located on the next page by clicking on button.

i have tried this. tfName is id of textfield in page 1.

```
 -(IBAction)onClick:(id)sender
{
 NSString *string1 =tfName.text;
}
```

and in page2

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
label1.text=string1;
}
```

Comment: Have u used storyboards??

Comment: are you using the storyboard or xib

Comment: please put your navigation or moving to your secondviewcontroller logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple example code:

Class A.h :

```
UITextfield *tfName;
```

Class A.m :

```
tfName.text = @"Hello world";




-(IBAction)onClick:(id)sender
{
    ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc]initwithnibname@"ClassB"];
     b.string1 =tfName.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:YES];
}
```

Class B.h :

```
@Property(..)NSString *string1;
```

Class B.m :

```
label1.text = _string1.
```

Note: you need to import ClassB in ClassA, i.e., `#import "ClassB.h"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First create ViewController object and then assign value to that property.

```
-(IBAction)onClick:(id)sender
    {
    SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        tempView. string1 = tfName.text;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempView animated:YES];

    }
```

on your `SecondViewController.h` create the one global string like

```
@Property(nonatomic, Strong)NSString *string1;
```

on your implementation  `SecondViewController.m` systensize your String like

```
@Synthesize string1;
```

finally call like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
 if (string1.length >0)
 label1.text=string1;
}
```

Comment: how can you pass the data in pop view controller , is it possible to direct pass...

Comment: sorry its pushviewcontroller not popViewController

Comment: where have you created string1 variable is it in on this page or calling page.

Comment: in SecondViewController create @Property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *string1; property

Comment: @KhyatiVaishnav -- check the updated answer , it works

Answer (score 0):

Make a Singleton class

```
class DataModel {

class var sharedInstance: DataModel {
    get {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: DataModel? = nil
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.token, {
            Static.instance = DataModel()
        })
        return Static.instance!
    }
}

var textData:String = ""
```

}

on button tap do this:

```
DataModel.sharedInstance.textData = "page 1 data"
```

on 2nd page viewDidLoad fund

```
label1.text = DataModel.sharedInstance.textData
```

That should work fine!